# Text search when already using WHERE IN clause

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a way to perform a text-search similar to SQL LIKE clause, when already using a `WHERE IN` clause.

I tried something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM cars 
WHERE driverName IN ("Bob", "Joe")
MATCH(name) AGAINST ('"mercedez"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But I can't get a working query based on the text-search term "mercedez"

Comment: `WHERE driverName IN ("Bob", "Joe") AND/OR name LIKE "%mercedez%"`

Comment: As @Veve says, you need to tell MySQL how you want to combine the two conditions (the `driverName in` clause and the `MATCH` clause) with `AND` or `OR` as appropriate. @Veve used `OR` but I suspect you intended `AND`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the names of cars with "mercedez" in it AND drived by "Bob" or "Joe", you can add an `AND` clause with wildcards (in case the name of the car contains other things than "mercedez"):

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM cars 
WHERE driverName IN ("Bob", "Joe")
AND name LIKE "%mercedez%";
```

If you want to get the names of cars with "mercedez" in it OR drived by "Bob" or "Joe", add an `OR` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM cars 
WHERE driverName IN ("Bob", "Joe")
OR name LIKE "%mercedez%";
```

Comment: How can I make this comparison case-insensitive? (Or is it already?)

Comment: `LIKE` is already insensitive with  the default `latin1` or `latin1_swedish_ci` collations. More infos here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html